# Of the changes to Rails between 1.x and 2.x which ones have actually affected your work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a course on Rails that focuses on version 1.1.6 so I'm trying to figure out which of the numerous changes between 1.x and 2.x are the most critical to be aware of for practical use. At the moment I don't need to know all the little nitty gritty changes - just the big ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that's can't-live-without critical, but there's a heap of wouldn't-want-to-live-without-it stuff.

OTTOMH:

- The built-in RESTfulness.
- named_scope
- improved finders
- no more `t.column` in migrations (t.[typename] is so much DRYer)
- the little improvements to test syntax in `ActiveSupport::TestCase`
- way better caching

Comment: Don't forget default_scope and locale support!

Comment: i18n isn't an issue for me right now, but it's nice to know it's there. default_scope is something I've yet to experience: it's going to be some time before I get to 2.3...

Answer (score 2):

well, most of them have, but the biggest thing from the 1.x to the 2.x codebase would probably be the emphasis and features for REST

also, I don't believe there ever was a 1.6 version.  I believe they were only 1.2.x versions

Comment: Indeed there's no rails 1.6, but the rails libraries like activerecord  had their own distinct version numbering during the 1.x releases, and I believe some of them reached 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [best summary I remember from back then](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/12/7/rails-2-0-final-released-summary-of-features).

If you're willing to part with some paltry cash, the [pdf book linked in that post](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-2-pdf) is also great. I ended up buying it for the better format. (Don't expect great typography though)